# Displaying a value on chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Hello i am trying to create a simple button game and i cannot get the value to be displayed on my chrome window.
here is my code and i'm trying to display the amount of money by using console.log().

```
   <button type="sheep" onclick="BuySheep(1)>
Sheep: <span id"Sheep">0</span><br />
Cost: <span id"SheepCost">10</span>
<var sheep = 0;>
function BuySheep(){
    var SheepCost = Math.floor(10*Math.pow(1.1,Sheep));
    if(Sheep >= SheepCost){
    Sheep = Sheep + 1;
    Money = Money - SheepCost;
    document.getElementById('Sheep').innerHTML = Sheep;
    document.getElementById('Money').innerHTML = Money;
    };
    var nextCost = Math.floor(10*Math.pow(1.1,Sheep));
    document.getElementById('Money').innerHTML = nextCost;

    window.setInterval(function(){
    MoneyClick(Sheep);
    console.log(Money);
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: There are many problems with your code. You are passing a variable to the function BuySheep, but not catching it in the function, you are missing closing brackets on your function, you are missing closing quotes on your onclick, etc...

Answer (score 1):

the main problem is that ur script is not in js section.
You should separate your html from your script.
You can write it in separate js file or include it by adding

```
<script type="text/javascript"src="scriptNameHere.js"></script>
```

in the head section or by wrapping it with tag  like this

```
<script>
function BuySheep(x){
  ...
}
</script>
```

Comment: He's got way more problems than that. His id's dont have equal signs, his variable for sheep is in <> for some unknown reason, the variable sheep isnt capitalized, yet later referenced as capitalized. The list goes on and on.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <button type="sheep" onclick="BuySheep(1)>
 Sheep: <span id"Sheep">0</span><br />
Cost: <span id"SheepCost">10</span>
<script type="text/javascript">
var sheep = 0;
function BuySheep(){
var SheepCost = Math.floor(10*Math.pow(1.1,Sheep));
if(Sheep >= SheepCost){
Sheep = Sheep + 1;
Money = Money - SheepCost;
document.getElementById('Sheep').innerHTML = Sheep;
document.getElementById('Money').innerHTML = Money;
};
var nextCost = Math.floor(10*Math.pow(1.1,Sheep));
document.getElementById('Money').innerHTML = nextCost;

window.setInterval(function(){
MoneyClick(Sheep);
console.log(Money);
}, 1000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I stripped down your project to bare necessities and made a Fiddle for you to work on it.

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/95Cyx/)

```
var Sheep = 0;
var Money = 100;
var SheepCost = 10;

function BuySheep() {
    Sheep++;
    $('#Sheep').html(Sheep);
    Money = Money - SheepCost;
}

window.setInterval(function () {
    console.log(Money);
}, 1000);
```

Apart from all the errors listed in my comments above, you were using variables that weren't even declared.